# E-mail a link don't working in document library

Tags: document-library, email

I'm looking for how to enable the option "E-mail a Link" in a document library (SharePoint 2010)
This option is available for the entire library, but not for one or more element in this library

I did the test with the Administrator account and the "E-mail a link button: is disabled.

Thank you

[image: capture]

Comment: Have you tried running your Browser as administrator?